# Intellij Idea + Maven: dependency version is wrong in run time

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

This is driving me crazy. Originally I had added Jackson v. 2.5.4 dependency to my project. Later, I updated it to use 2.6.4 like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

When writing the code I can see that the new version features are there. Also, when I go to project settings under modules and artifacts everything there says jackson 2.6.4.

But, when I run the program, clearly it's using version 2.5.4. I see that the new feature added in 2.6.0 is not there, also I checked:

```
System.out.println(ObjectMapper.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion());
```

and the output is 2.5.4...

I rebuilt the project, re-imported dependencies and restarted intellij several times....
please help...

Comment: do a mvn dependency:tree in the root of your project, and doublecheck that you don't have 2.5.4 included transitively.

Comment: Can you show the full pom file?

Answer (score 7):

#### Step 1:

Open the project's folder, then go to : `.idea/libraries/` you should find here a file by maven dependency.
Delete the `jackson-core` and `jackson-databinding` files.

#### Step 2: Remove maven dependency

Remove the two dependencies from `pom.xml' file. (do not comment out, erase the lines).

#### Step 3: Check Intellij project config

Open `project structure` windows (clic on the top parent folder in Intellij then press F4), then go to `Libraries` tab. ensure the two dependencies are not present, if there are, delete them as well (with the '-' button at top).

#### Step 4: Remove all cached maven libraries

Go to your home folder, for windows : `C:\Users\<YOUR_NAME>\.m2\`, here remove the repository folder.

#### Step 5: Reimport the project

In intellij : Right  click the top folder of your project then `> Maven > Reimport`.

#### Step 6: Add maven dep

Add your two dependencies to `pom.xml`.

#### Step 8: Build your project.

Launch your project.

This should work.

Comment: How does this affect maven beside forcing it to download every single dependency again?

Comment: @SatelliteSD i believe there is a weird behavior in intellij because i encountered such a problem last week, this solved my problem, i don't even know why, but ....

Comment: If the build contains 2.5.4 it is a maven issue not IDE.

Comment: In my case no, it was an IDE issue, intellij kept storing the wrong version in his configuration.

Comment: Maven is not very interested in IDE configs.

Comment: i know, but in my case it was a spring-boot project, and even if i use maven for the project, when i click the `start` project, intellij seems not to use `mvn` to build the project, (i know it is strange, but some project launch config interact with configurations)

Comment: I know the question, he never sayed that he use the `maven launch configuration`, you starts being anoying, if you have a better solution post it below...

Comment: I know what you said and you are wrong. No matter what launch configuration you may come up with, maven relies on poms.

Comment: Step 1 solved my problem (ver 2020.2). THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Run the maven command "mvn dependency:tree" in the directory which contains the parent pomx.mxl file, you can find if you have 2.5.4 there. Maybe you add other jars which also import version 2.5.4, then you should exclude the 2.5.4 version.

Also you can check the local Maven repository, and delete the 2.5.4 version Jackson.

Comment: deletion won't help anything, because it would just be downloaded again. Also he has to determine dependencies at root level, because of maven dependency convergence.

Comment: yes, you are right. But delete the 2.5.4 version could check if the processing of build will download this version again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one of my dependencies. I went to the `.m2/repository` directory and manually deleted the unwanted dependencies that were there. I only kept the version I wanted in the `m2` directory. Then I invalidated my caches and restarted IntelliJ IDEA. That seemed to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's and old post but just in case, what worked for me in newer version (2023.1.2) is to delete manually the cached faulty version. It can be done by

1. In Project hierarchy find "External Libraries" and the faulty dependency in it.
2. Right click -> Open Library Settings (or Left click -> F4)
3. This will open "Project Structure/Libraries" (ctrl + shift + alt + s) with the dependency selected in the list.
4. Click on the "-" icon on top of the list. Confirm. Reimport maven and it should download the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

For me deleting the dependecy in my .m2 didnt help, neither did clearing the cache idea. In the end I just had to reclone my repo and it worked.